# Java Array Inheritance

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I seem to be having issues understanding how to go about a particular issue.

I need to write a class that holds an array with four elements. Each element has a different method.

For example the first element is to inherit information from another class, initially a number is entered and then that number as well as a char (letter grade) that corresponds to that number is returned. Both those items need to be stored in that element.

Below is my class which takes the input (score) and returns the letter grade

```
package runit;

public class GradedActivity{
    public int score;

    public GradedActivity(int score)
    {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public void setScore(int s)
    {
        score = s;
    }

    public double getScore()
    {
        return score;
    }

    public char getGrade()
    {
        char letterGrade;

        if (score>= 90)
            letterGrade = 'A';
        else if (score >= 80)
            letterGrade = 'B';
        else if (score >= 70)
            letterGrade = 'C';
        else if (score >= 60)
            letterGrade = 'D';
        else
            letterGrade = 'F';

        return letterGrade;
    }
}
```

Below is my main class, used at this point just for getting the individual scores needed for each element

```
package runit;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RunIt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int labScore;
        int essayScore;
        int finalExamScore;


        System.out.print("Enter the students score for the lab: ");
        labScore = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the students score for the essay: ");      
        essayScore = keyboard.nextInt();        
        System.out.print("Enter the students score for the final exam: ");
        finalExamScore = keyboard.nextInt();

        GradedActivity a = new GradedActivity(labScore);
        GradedActivity b = new GradedActivity(essayScore);   



        //below was used to make sure the GradedActivity class was working

        System.out.println(a.getScore() + " " + a.getGrade()); 
        System.out.println(b.getScore() + " " + b.getGrade());
    }

}
```

The next part is where I seem to be having the issue.  I'm not sure if I'm over thinking it, or possibly confusing parts of it with JavaScript.  Essentially each elements method has to hold an inputted score and the corresponding letter grade. While I know I could easily do that with just creating separate instances in my main class, such as

```
GradedActivity a = new GradedActivity(labScore);
```

the whole array in another class is whats throwing me off.

Below is the class with the array

```
public class CourseGrades extends GradedActivity{
    //I initially had private int[] grades, though I wasn't seeming to make any progress
    enum grades {
        lab,
        essay,
        finalExam,   
    };

    private int lab;
    private int essay;
    private int finalExam;

    public CourseGrades(int score, int lab, int essay, int finalExam) {
        super(score);
        this.lab = lab;
        this.essay = essay;
        this.finalExam = finalExam;
    }


    public void setLab(int score) {
        this.lab = score;
    }

    public void setEssay(int score) {
        this.essay = score;
    }

    public void setFinalExam(int finalExam) {
        this.finalExam = finalExam;
    }

    //lastly, I need to be able to print out both the numeric and letter grade for each element

    public String toString() {
        return "Lab grade: " + lab + " Essay grade: " + essay + " Final Exam grade: " + finalExam;
    }
}
```

I've also tried using `CourseGrades c = new CourseGrades(labScore, essayScore, finalExam);` but it then requires a 4th int (for the super(score)).

I appreciate any help you may lend. I'm racking my brain trying to figure this out. Thank you.

Comment: `CourseGrades` should not extend `GradedActivity` but rather contain an instance of a `GradedActivity`.

Comment: Where do "Java Array"s come into this question? (See the title and tags)

Comment: I would suggest taking a step back and re-examining your design a little further.  The phrase "each element [of the array] has a different method" *screams* bad OOP design.  Perhaps you could have an object hold this data, or perhaps you're representing something in a more complex manner now because of another design error earlier on, and now you're in a trap.  Whatever the reason, I'm all but certain the right answer is to not do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Peter- I need to be able to store both the letterGrade and the numeric score for four different elements. From there I need to be able to display each element (and both pieces of data).

Comment: In the code above there is no Array object given by you. You have used int variables with private access modifiers.

Comment: @Wang : You have applied wrong logic at `getGrade()`. Suppose you get a score of 75 which is greater than 60 and 70, So your letterGrade will be C as well as D . This part is ambiguous.

Comment: I pretty much scratched it and started over from the beginning. I now have it working. Thank you for the help. (If you would like to see the working code just let me know)

Answer (score 0):

You create an array of your GradedActivity class.

```
private GradedActivity[] grades;
```

You initialize it like any array,

```
grades = new GradedActivity[4];
```

You add each element like this, assuming you can set your grades in a for loop.  You can also use the numbers 0, 1, 2, and 3 to reference your 4 grades.

```
grades[i] = new GradedActivity(score);
```

You reference the GradedActivity methods like this.

```
char c = grades[i].getGrade()
```